# How do the costs for Quiver cards work?

Tags: tainted-grail-conquest

The description for the **Quiver** keyword reads:

> Allows you to offer your **Energy** and/or **Ultimate Charges** to draw more **Arrow** cards.

However, the Arrow Bag card that the Sentinel starts with has both symbols, and seems to require both to play.

Does the "or" in that "and/or" just mean that any card that lists both requires both, but some **Quiver** cards exist that have only 1 type of cost? Or am I missing some way to play the card by paying only one of the two costs?